# What is the difference between these two phrases used by Poskim?

Tags: hebrew, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, business, aramaic, parnassah-livelihood

I have seen both **Mekach U’Memchar** and **Masa U’Masan** used by various Rabbis and Poskim to mean, what I think, is business or business dealings. Is there a difference between these two phrases in meaning?

Comment: Isn't there a dagesh in the ת of משא ומתן?

Comment: @Deu also the כ of ממכר

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Masa umatan is a larger spectrum. It's also in other context